# Angular директива отслеживающая изменение атрибутов input'a

Tags: angularjs, директива

**Что пытаюсь сделать:**

Директива которая обнуляет(очищает) значение модели если input элемента является disabled (или стал disabled).

**Что не понимаю:**

- Как отслеживать изменение атрибута disabled данного инпута (к которому применена директива) ?
- Является ли отслеживание изменения атрибута правильным путем решения данной задачи? (Или есть другой, более правильный путь?)

Пример. Есть input с ng-model, в зависимости от состояния disabled - очищать значение в модели ng-model

```
<input type="text" 
   name="input_name" 
   ng-model="data.another_data" 
   required 
   disabled-to-null
   ng-disabled="restrict"/>
```

Comment: Значение атрибута в данном случае задается переменной `restrict` достаточно добавить watch на нее и следить за ее изменением

Comment: @Grundy Значение ng-disabled, в моём случае задается различными выражениями и переменными, необходимо следить именно за самим фактом того что форма стала disabled

Comment: вы уже используете директиву `ng-disabled` которая добавляет нудный атрибут в зависимости от выражения, так что не вижу противоречия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно сделать. И с помощью директивы, вы идете в правильном направлении.

Как сказал @Grundy, элемент сам будет становиться `disabled` по выражению в `ng-disabled`.

Живой пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwcq9svr/1/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      another_data: null
    };
    $scope.data1 = {
      another_data: null
    };
  })
  .directive('disabledToNull', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "ngModel",
      scope: {
        ngModel: "=",
        ngDisabled: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelController) {
        scope.$watch('ngDisabled', function(newVal) {
          if (newVal) { // Если элемент disabled
            scope.ngModel = null;
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <h3>
    Без проверок
    </h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="restrict">Выключить</label>
    <input type="text" name="input_name" ng-model="data.another_data" required disabled-to-null ng-disabled="restrict" />
    <pre>data={{data|json}}</pre>
    <h3>
    С min-length 3
    </h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="restrict1">Выключить</label>
    <input type="text" name="input_name" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="data1.another_data" required disabled-to-null ng-disabled="restrict1" />

    <pre>data1={{data1|json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в принципе можно было `ngModelController` использовать, раз уж все равно как параметр есть, и вместо `ngDisabled: "="` лучше что-то другое, возможно лучше вообще без скока и в вотч вставлять значение из атрибута, чтобы лишних наблюдателей не плодить

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен. Можно и без `scope` написать, использовать `ngModelController`. Можно и `$observe` использовать длч аттрибута `disabled`. Прелесть программирования - одно и то же можно сделать разными путями.

Comment: на счет `$observe` тут бы поспорил, если не ошибаюсь он будет работать только с интерполированными строками типа `{{angularexpression}}`, поэтому если в значении атрибута это не используется то отследить изменения не получиться

Comment: Спорить не надо, вы абсолютно правы. Поскольку `$observe` смотрит на значение аттрибута в **DOM**, а оно не меняется, то и отслеживать изменения `$observe` не будет.